2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #2 on Islam has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

I think the answer section on this post is more suited for existing mods to post in and welcome UmH, but I have said it before with different words and am saying it again. UmH is from a group of handful users who regularly maintain the site's quality, provide well-referenced academic answers, and combat misinformation. I cannot thank enough, primarily, UmH as well as, goldPseudo, Medi1Saif, AbdulRahman, owari, AK, and some others, who have spent their time consistently to keep the site up to StackExchange standards. Without them, the site would be like Quora, a pool of advices and opinions.

That all being said, I pray that Allah blesses, guides, and bring close to him all the people who maintain quality content on this site, regardless of the sect or denomination of Islam they follow, Aameen.
